# IIF con Between

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Trato de meter una consulta con varios `IIF` anidados y `Between` en `Oracle SQL Developer` pero no me esta funcionando.

Esta es parte de la consulta donde trato de meter el IFF y Between:

```
SELECT T77.PLANT_ID AS PLANT_ID, T77.CABLE_LENGTH AS LONGITUD,
IIf([CABLE_LENGTH] Between 1 And 500,"Rng1", IIf([CABLE_LENGTH] Between 501 And 1000, "Rng2", IIf([CABLE_LENGTH] Between 1001 And 1500, "Rng3", "OutRng"))) AS Rngs FROM T77
```

He reformulado con la sentencia `IIF` sin  el uso de `Betwwen` tampoco me corre:

```
SELECT T77.PLANT_ID, T77.CABLE_LENGTH,
IIf([CABLE_LENGTH]>=1 And [CABLE_LENGTH]<=500,"Rng1",
IIf([CABLE_LENGTH]>=501 And [CABLE_LENGTH]<=2000,"Rng2","OutRng")) AS "Rangos"
FROM T77
```

NOTA: Cabe mencionar que en esta consulta me faltan muchos mas `IIF` y `Between` en rangos de 500 hasta el 15000.

Me arroja este error:

> ORA-00936: missing expression
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 2 Column: 5

O si hay alguna forma mas simple de realizarlo agradecería el aporte.

Saludos,
DS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso, preferiría el uso de Case, del siguiente modo:

```
  SELECT T77.PLANT_ID AS PLANT_ID,
     T77.CABLE_LENGTH AS LONGITUD,
     CASE
       WHEN CABLE_LENGTH Between 1 And 500
         THEN 'Rng1'
       WHEN CABLE_LENGTH Between 501 And 1000
         THEN 'Rng2'
       WHEN CABLE_LENGTH Between 1001 And 1500
         THEN 'Rng3'
       ELSE 'OutRng'
     END AS Rngs
  FROM T77
```

Me parece que es más clara la sintaxis (y mantenible).

Comment: Gracias es correcto es mucho mas clara esta sintaxis.